# Android Styles and Values issue

Tags: android, styles

My Android project was working fine when I noticed that I had checked SDK version 4.2 when I meant to target Google 2.33.  I set the project back to G2.33 (In the manifest it minsdk = 8 targetsdk=11) and now I have errors on two different styles.xml files in two folders named Values-v11 and values-v14.

the styles.xml in the Values-v14 folder has an error on the following line...

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

the st yles.xml in the Values-v11 folder has an error on ...

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
```

My other projects, that all target 2.33 don't even have these folders.  What is the best way of me getting out of this mess?
Thanks, Gary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply delete these folders if you don't want anything specific for SDK level 11, and the one for 14 won't be used anyway if your targetsdk is 11.

If you want to retain the one for api level 11 for custom behaviour in API level 11, you need to set the project to compile with API level 11 - i.e. if in Eclipse, select the project, go to Properties, select Android and then set the project build target to "Android 3.0" or "Google APIs" for API level 11 if you need the Google APIs.

Comment: I did delete those folders which led to another problem, then another, then another etc.  Had a mess for nearly two days.